# ArcMap: Combining County Polygons for 3 separate states into one layer with attributes

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-joins, spatial-join, union

I have 3 separate layers with the counties for 3 separate states: WA, OR, & ID. I want to combine them into one layer "Counties" so they all share an attribute table with the same fields. I am having issues with the Spatial Join and Union tools where instead of joining the fields, it creates new fields with the same names. The following image shows what I am describing.

[image: Fields not joining]

How can I either have the layers merge and their attributes combine into one field. OR could I create a new field and populate it using the field calculator? I've tried my luck at writing an expression but my SQL and Python are very weak.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out... kinda. Seems like a work-around but nonetheless I got the result I was looking for.

I performed a Union between the county layers and then created a new field in the resulting layer's attribute table. I used the field calculator and added the 3 NAMELSAD fields together. The Union operation generated some polygon slivers where the county layers overlapped, so I had to go through and individually delete those in an edit session. Then I performed a spatial join between my new County layer and a State layer to get the State field associated with the Counties so they can be queried on that basis.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The [Merge](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) tool is what you want.

(I'll add that since you noticed sliver polygons after running Union, there will be overlapping areas -- but no slivers -- in the output.)